# How to crop a field Length in SQL so it does not consume all the space of a DBGrid?

Tags: mysql, delphi, firebird, delphi-2006

Let's say I have this table:

```
name        varchar(255),
quantity    integer,
value       float
```

When I used this code:

```
select left(name, 99), quantity, value from table;
```

But I've got all the 255 spaces (by space I mean width length, not the real space chars) on the first column of the `dbgrid` and the other two fields where away unless I used the scroll bar and my objective was to make scroll bars not necessary.

**How do I get this goal correctly? I use Firebird and MySQL.**

*I can not do this by pascal code nor define it on the Fields object of the table component because this codes comes from many tables as this is a report generator and the first field is not always the same and for each report I have to use a different SQL code.*

[image]

**PLEASE, EVERYBODY READ THE ALL QUESTION BEFORE ANSWERING. THE FIRST 3 ANSWER WHERE WRONG BECAUSE THEY DID NOT CONSIDERED WHAT AS WRITTEN IN THE LAST PARAGRAPH!**

Comment: Did you tried to set `TField.DisplayWidth`?

Comment: As I said in the question: "I can not do this by pascal code nor define it on the Fields object of the table component because this codes comes from many tables as this is a report generator and the first field is not always the same and for each report I have to use a different SQL code.". Thanks!

Comment: Please see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've said you can't do it on the `TField` level or in your Delphi code, you can use `Trim()` or `Left()`, depending on the database you're using, on the column to remove the blank spaces you don't want to display:

For instance, in many SQL dialects you could use something like:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Trim(Col3) as Col3 FROM yourtable 
WHERE somecondition
```

Some allow this instead:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Left(Col3, MaxCharWidthAllowed) as Col3 FROM yourtable 
WHERE somecondition
```

or

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Substring(Col3, 1, MaxCharWidth) as Col3 FROM yourtable
```

As a quick test (I don't have FB, but have SQL Server 2008, so I used it), I created the following test data in SQL Server Management Studio:

[image: Test data in SSMS]

I then created a new D2007 VCL Forms application, and performed the following steps:

- Dropped an `TADOConnection` on the form (`ADOConnection1`), and set up the connection string to the test data above
- Dropped two `TADOQuery` components on the form (`ADOQuery1` and `ADOQuery2`), and set their `Connection` properties to `ADOConnection1`
- Dropped two `TDataSource` components on the form (`DataSource1` and `DataSource2`) and connected their `DataSet` properties to the matching `ADOQuery1` and `ADOQuery2`
- Dropped two `TDBGrid` components (`DBGrid1` and `DBGrid2`) and set their `DataSource` properties to the matching `DataSource1` and `DataSource2`.
- Added `SELECT * FROM test` to the SQL for `ADOQuery1`
- Added `SELECT Substring(itemname, 1, 30) as itemname, quantity, value FROM test` as the `SQL` of `ADOQuery2`. The length of `30` was arbitrarily chosen as being a small enough value to demonstrate the considerably smaller column width.
- Set `ADOConnection1.Connected` to `True`, and set both `TADOQuery.Active` properties to `True`.

The above produced this output (at design time, without ever compiling or running the application), with the top grid being `DBGrid1`:

[image: Design-time output of above steps]

As you can see, in `DBGrid2`, which is connected to `ADOQuery2` with the `Substring` in the SQL, the first column is correctly sized to 30 characters width.

Comment: As I sayd in the quetion, I've tryed this, but it did not work.

Comment: Note: There are no blank spaces before nor after the field contents.

Comment: As I said, you can use `Left()` or `SubString()` on the query, and Delphi will adjust the grid column to match the number of characters in that column. (As long as you're not using persistent fields, that is - if you're using persistent fields, the column width is stored as whatever the width is in the table definition itself.)

Comment: Now that you mentioned persistent fields, I went to check it out and it's not. So I have used Left, Trim, SubString and no good result. I will put pictures to show you guys.

Comment: Thank you Ken for your effort but this did not worked on firebird 2.0 and delphi 2006.

Comment: Just to be complete - I'm not installing FB 2 just to solve this ;-) - a quick check of the [docs for FB](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-substring.html) shows the syntax for `SubString` is `SUBSTRING (str FROM startpos [FOR length])`, which would mean it would be `SUBSTRING(ItemName FROM 1 FOR 30) AS itemname` for the sample data I provided above if I'm reading it correctly. Perhaps if you try the query from ISQL or some other FB utility (other than your app) you can see if the function is working correctly, or someone else can test it.

Comment: I always use InterBase Expert to test my Firebird queries. But it showed the same problem.

Comment: Select 
 SUBSTRING("Empresas"."Nome" FROM 1 FOR 30) Convenio, 
 Count("Exames_Requisitados"."Exame") Quantidade,
 SUM("Exames_Requisitados"."Repasse") Repasse

FROM "Exames_Requisitados" LEFT JOIN "Empresas" ON "Empresas"."Chave" = "Exames_Requisitados"."Convenio"

WHERE

 ("Exames_Requisitados"."Convenio" <> '') 

 
Group By
 Convenio

Order By
 Repasse DESC /* "Exames_Requisitados"."Convenio" */

Comment: For your test query, simplify it so you can see what's actually happening: `SELECT Nome, SUBSTRING(Nome FROM 1 TO 20) Convenio FROM Empresas WHERE Nome IS NOT NULL` or something similar - when testing, eliminate all possible noise and clutter from the test. The `COUNT`, `JOIN`, `SUM`, `Order By`, `Group By` etc. are clutter. I've tested in SQL Server, SQLite, and Advantage Database Server, and they all work as I'd expect. MySQL (according to SQLFiddle) is unclear; SQLFiddle puts things in a table that may affect things.

Answer (score 3):

If the column type is really `varchar(255)` and not `char(255)` then there shouldn't be any spaces in the end of the value unless you saved the spaces yourself. IOW the `varchar(255)` values will be returned to you exactly as you saved them into the table whether `char(255)` values will be right padded with spaces so that you always get string with 255 characters.

Thus I'd say that if you use `varchar` type and you don't pad the values with spaces when saving them into the DB then the problem is really in the grid and you can't solve it usimg `trim()` or equivalent in SQL. Most likely the grid reads the field's definition, sees that the max length of the value is 255 characters and sets the column width accordingly. So the solution is really to set the column width manually or use column's `ApplyBestFit` method (if it has one).

Comment: There are not spaces, what I was trying to says was that DBGrid.Columns[0].Width was automatically set for accommodation of 255 chars.

Comment: The DBGrid sets it automatically based on the column definition, unless you do something specifically that reduces it. (See my answer, where `Substring` or `Left` will indeed fix it.)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of limiting the length of a field displayed in a DBGrid that do not alter the data from the database.  One is by setting the DisplayWidth of the field and the other is setting the Width of the grid column.

You can set the DisplayWidth in the After open event of the query. The example is for ZeosLib and assumes the first field is the one to be limited.  This would need to be added to each Query.

```
procedure TForm1.ZQuery1AfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
  DataSet.Fields[0].DisplayWidth := 99;
end;
```

or use a procedure to set the DBGrid Column Width after the query is opened.  This example lets you specify the column as well as the width.

```
procedure TForm1.SetColWidth(c,w: integer);
begin
  if DBGrid1.Columns.Count > c then
    DBGrid1.Columns[c].Width := w;
end;
```

Comment: Does anybody read the all question? I can't use pascal code nor DBGrid's properties or methods because it's displaying results from many different `SELECT` codes because it's a report display, so the first (and other fields) aren't the same in every time. Not the same in name, size nor type.

Comment: I thought I was missing something, but I am begging to think that maybe Firebird has this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**

Delphi takes as **default** for **Displaylength** the length of the varchar field. varchar(255) = Displaylength = 255.

Can I change this behavior with "SQL". **NO**
If the result is only 99 characters long, the length varchar (255) = 255 and Displaylength = 255 .

Compare it!
allowed:

```
select left(name,99), quantity, value from table;
```

- Sql should quickly deliver a dataset (not the design of a report).
- For each table for each varchar field, you have to set an extra SQL statement `(xname,99)`
- Can I see, truncated (perhaps important) information? Never.

wy not allowed:

```
Columns[index].Width = 99;
```

- Easier to design a report.
- Easier select SQL statement: `select name, quantity, value from table`
- Simple expand column with mouse to see hidden information.
- Good Design: The column size of a DBGrid should be that you can see at least 2 columns at once.

**The program should take over the design.**

*I can not do this by pascal code nor define it on the Fields object of the table component because this code comes from many tables as this is a report generator.*

*and for each report I have to use a different SQL code.*

Who generates this "different SQL code"?
I think similar lines are used to generate the code (Pascal code).

Allowed: Pascal code

```
   Query1.Close;
   Query1.SQL.Clear;
   Query1.SQL.Add ('select name, quantity, value from table');
   Query1.Active: = true;
```

why not allowed: Pascal code

```
   Columns[index].Width := 99;
```

you can do it with an automatic adjustment of the columns. All columns wider a certain size are to be adapted to their actual width. That's still better than a fixed size = 99.

The following program has been tested with Rad Studio 2007 and Zeos Components.
Firebird 2.5, on a Windows 2000 computer.

- A) Zeos Components.
- B) DBGrid1 no active data connection.
- C) Firebird automatically allocated size for varchar (255).
- D) The running Program. "use Me" is used to automatically size the column.

For lack of time, I created only 2 data fields.

[image]

If the entire source code is required for download, let me know.

```
unit FBAuto;
{
~Zarko Gajic
About Delphi Programing
http://delphi.about.com
customized 2013
moskito-x software
}

interface

uses
  Math,
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, DB, DBTables, Grids, DBGrids, ExtCtrls, StdCtrls, ZAbstractRODataset,
  ZAbstractDataset, ZDataset, ZConnection;

type
  TAutoColumnWidth = record
    Index : integer;
    Width : integer;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
    ZConnection1: TZConnection;
    ZQuery1: TZQuery;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    CBuseMe: TCheckBox;
    DBGrid2: TDBGrid;
    ZQuery2: TZQuery;
    DataSource2: TDataSource;
    IntegerField1: TIntegerField;
    StringField1: TStringField;
    procedure DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject; const Rect: TRect;
      DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure CBuseMeClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure SetFit;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

var
  AutoColumnWidth : TAutoColumnWidth;
  useMe :Boolean;

procedure TForm1.SetFit;
var
  i:integer;
begin
  if NOT CBuseMe.Checked then begin
  for i := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count - 1 do begin
     if DBGrid1.Columns[i].Field.Size > 300 then
        DBGrid1.Columns[i].Width := DBGrid1.Columns[i].Field.Size;
  end;
  end else begin
  useMe:=true;
  for i := 0 to DBGrid1.Columns.Count - 1 do begin
  AutoColumnWidth.Index:=-1;
  if DBGrid1.Columns[i].Field.DisplayWidth > 200 then  AutoColumnWidth.Index:=i;
     if AutoColumnWidth.Index > -1 then begin
        AutoColumnWidth.Width := -1;
        DBGrid1.Repaint;
        DBGrid1.Columns[AutoColumnWidth.Index].Width := AutoColumnWidth.Width+ 5;
     end;
  end;
  useMe:=false;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
ZQuery1.Active:=true;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AutoColumnWidth.Index := -1;
  AutoColumnWidth.Width := -1;
  useMe:=false;
end;

procedure TForm1.CBuseMeClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  setFit;
end;

procedure TForm1.DBGrid1DrawColumnCell(
  Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
begin
  if useMe then begin
   if DataCol = AutoColumnWidth.Index then
   begin
    if Assigned(Column.Field) then
    begin
      AutoColumnWidth.Width := Max(AutoColumnWidth.Width, DBGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(Column.Field.DisplayText));
    end;
   end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

**> 200** to adapt it to your needs can be set.

```
if DBGrid1.Columns[i].Field.DisplayWidth > 200 then  AutoColumnWidth.Index:=i;
```

I hope this helps a little, or may lead into the right direction.